# Is it not possible to run Linux and Windows docker containers simultaneously?

Tags: docker

Based on [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/run-your-first-container), in order to run a Windows containers:

> If you see an error message that says `no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries`, make sure Docker isn't
> configured to run Linux containers. To switch to Windows containers in
> Docker, right-click the Docker icon, and select Switch to Windows
> containers. To use the command line to switch between containers, `run & $Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon`.

This seems problematic (I just tried it and got the error mentioned) since I want to run a test lab with Windows and Linux boxes interacting on a network. Is docker not capable of this or have I perhaps misunderstood something?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to run Windows containers and Linux containers. The only drawback is that you cannot manage (e.g. start, stop) Windows and Linux containers at the same time without switching.

If you select "Switch to Windows containers", you get this message:

> You are about to switch to Windows containers. Existing containers will continue to run, but you will not be able to manage them until you switch back to linux containers. No data will be lost otherwise.
> Do you want to continue?